# Reference MovieClip After it is Added to Stage as a Child

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am currently having problems referencing a `MovieClip` child which I add to the `Stage` from the `Document` Class. Basically when the `MovieClip` child is added to the `Stage` from the `Document` Class, I want a certain `MovieClip` already on the `Stage` to reference it once it is on the `Stage`.

Also, **if it is possible**, I don't want the `MovieClip` referencing the child being added to the `Stage` to have parameters linking it with the `Document` Class, because I plan on nesting this `MovieClip` within another `MovieClip` later on in the future.

Here is the code for the `MovieClip` class which is referencing the child once it is added to the `Stage`:

```
package com.gameEngine.assetHolders
{
    import com.gameEngine.documentClass.*;
    import com.gameEngine.assetHolders.*;
    import com.gameEngine.assetHolders.Levels.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class FallingPlatform extends MovieClip
    {
        public var _document:Document;
        // Trying to reference "_player"
        public var _player:Player;
        public var fallState:Boolean;
        public var platformYSpeed:Number = 0;
        public var platformGravityPower:Number = 0.75;

        public function FallingPlatform()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initFallingPlatform);
            // constructor code
        }
        public function initFallingPlatform(event:Event)
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dynamicFall);
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTest);
        }
        public function dynamicFall(event:Event)
        {
            if (this.fallState)
            {
                this.platformYSpeed += this.platformGravityPower;
                y += this.platformYSpeed;
            }
        }
        // Trying to reference "_player"
        public function hitTest(event:Event)
        {
            if (this.hitTestPoint(_player.x, _player.y + 1, true))
            {
                this.fallState = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player is initialized in the Document class, right? So for me, the best option is either passing the player reference in the constructor of your FallingPlatform class like this

```
 public function FallingPlatform (thePlayer:Player) {
      this._player = thePlayer
 }
```

or having a setter method to pass it to it. In this way, you're not tying the structure of your code

```
 public function set player (thePlayer:Player):void {
       this._player = thePlayer
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you set a document class for a fla file every movieclip on the stage can be accessed by it's instance name - just as you wold create a var  with its name.
Event more, you can do something like that:

If you place two movieclips on the stagefor example mc1 and mc2 you can add them as variables to the document class.

```
package{
    public class DocClass{

    public var mc1:MovieClip;
    public var mc2:MovieClip;

    [...]

    }
}
```

and than you can access those movieclips from your class with code hints form your IDE (flash or flashbuilder)

the opposite is also availible: define variables in your class and than access them in flash

! it works best when your document class extends a Sprite, I haven;t tested it on extending from a MovieClip but it should also work

Comment: Alright, I've replaced "_player" with "_document._player" in the hitTest function, but now I'm getting Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Any idea on how to fix this error?

Comment: Is the _documment property initiated somwhere? Maybe you should create an static variable for holding the instance of the document

Comment: The code is still the same as last time except that I've replaced "_player" with "_document._player" in the hitTest function. The "_document" property is initialized in the FallingPlatform class (the class that I've posted), but am I doing it correctly or not?

Comment: I don't see a _document instance created. You've only defined the property but without a constructor or a reference to an instance of the object you're variable is still null